# How do I interpret the Death Recap for regular hits and headshots?

Tags: apex-legends

With the rising prevalence of AI aimbots and cheaters in Apex Legends, I have heard several youtube content creators mention that reviewing your Death Recap for an unusually high amount of crits/headshots is important to identify if someone is enhancing their ability to kill you, especially if it seemed very quick. Problem is, I don't know what I'm looking at. Where are the headshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Death Recap screen under the numbers representing damage dealt there will be little diamonds, these are the bullets taken. A headshot will be a brighter colored diamond.

In the example you can see that 104 damage was dealt by the same gun twice. Once in 6 bullets once in 5 bullets one of which was a headshot (LMGs had a 2x headshot modifier prior to Season 10).

[image]